# Create configuration file for aspell

Tags: 16.04, spell-checking

After install `aspell` I was looking for any configuration file

```
~$ aspell dump config
# conf (string)
#   main configuration file
# default: aspell.conf

# conf-dir (string)
#   location of main configuration file
# default: /etc
.
.
.
```

but I couldn't find one

```
~$ sudo find / -iname "*aspell*.conf"
```

How to create a global configuration file, just execute `sudo aspell --conf "aspell.conf" --conf-dir "/etc"`?

```
:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Based on the man page, it looks like the default is `/etc/aspell.conf` - so you can just create that file if it does not already exist. Or put personal configuration options in `~/.aspell.conf`.

Comment: @steeldriver, the man page says also _"... The /etc/aspell.conf file is a good example of how to set these options ..."_ But what should be the default content if I would just create the config file on my own?

Comment: . . . what are you trying to configure? I don't think it needs any default content - the idea is to overwrite specific name-value pairs with *non* default values

Comment: @steeldriver, I want to add different dictionaries, but this is not the question. My question was about the "... good example..." but I couldn't find the example.

Answer (score 0):

Create one: /etc/aspell.conf

Or in newer versions, I believe it is in: /usr/local/etc